# AlloyUI Ace-Editor Theme Change

Tags: ace-editor, alloy-ui

I am not able to find a way to change the Ace-Editor that is built into the AllouUI widget.  The example below is what I would like to achieve with the theme attribute.

`YUI().use(
          'aui-ace-autocomplete-base',
          function(Y) {
            var editor = new Y.AceEditor(
              {
                boundingBox: '#myEditor',
                height: '200',
                mode: 'python',
                value: 'print("Hello there!!!")',
                width: '700',
                theme: 'chaos'
              }
            ).render();`

Sadly, there in the code there are no predefined ways I saw to change the theme.

Is there a way change the theme to ace editor for alloyui's widget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if Y.AceEditor component exposes the required api, but you can try to get the real ace editor object, which allows to change the theme dynamically

```
document.getElementById('#myEditor').env.editor.setTheme("ace/theme/chtome")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to call [`AceEditor.getEditor()`](https://alloyui.com/api/classes/A.AceEditor.html#method_getEditor)`.setTheme()`:

```
editor.getEditor().setTheme('ace/theme/twilight');
```